# Google Analytics not found for iOS/Watchkit app

Tags: swift, cocoapods, watchkit

I have an already existing project that uses GoogleAnalytics (cocoapods). It compiles fine, but now I need to add a watchkit target to it.

But when I do and then try to compile, the Bridging-Header throws an error.

This is what the bridging -header has.

```
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAIFields.h>
#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAIDictionaryBuilder.h>
```

This is the error: 'GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h' file not found. Actually it cannot find any of those 3 files.

Not sure how to proceed, it seems like the Birdging-Header file cannot find the Analytics pods but they are indeed in the workspace as they worked fine without the Watchkit Target

Comment: Does the WatchKit target in the Podfile depend on GoogleAnalytics?

Comment: No it doesn't. I tried changing the bridging file to an empty file but then it crashed with no error, just doesn't build.

Comment: The target should depend on GoogleAnalytics for it to find the headers.

Comment: Turs out I just had to delete the Birdging Header File for the watchkit app on the build settings of the target. Then it compiled but started throwing other errores regarding the bundle id. I also fixed it by manually entering the right values on the info.plist. Thank you for your help.